# Detect if no JavaScript is build for specific browser in GWT

Tags: gwt

We are required to support only IE8 and IE9 and no other browsers. When using Chrome or Firefox all I get is a blank page (the host page). Is there a way to detect or be informed that no js file was found for that browser? Or do I have to look at the user agent myself in the host page and show message if the browser is not IE8 or IE9?

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to solve this problem, but the usual gwt way is using [Deferred-Binding](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html)

Just create a class for loading the app code and instantiate it using `GWT.create()` in your `onModuleLoad`. Then you can have different implementations of the class for each permutation.

```java
  package mynamespace.client;
  ...

  public class MyEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
      // create the appropriate implementation of the App class
      App app = GWT.create(App.class);
      // call the method to load the application.
      app.onLoad();
    }

    // Default implementation
    public static class App {
      public void onLoad() {
        Window.alert("This App is only supported in IE");
      }
    }

    // Implementation for IE
    public static class AppIE extends App {
      public void onLoad() {
        Window.alert("This is a supported Browser");
      }
    }
  }
```

Define which implementation use per each user-agent in your `.gwt.xml` file:

```xml
  <replace-with class="mynamespace.client.MyEntryPoint.AppIE">
    <when-type-is class="mynamespace.client.MyEntryPoint.App"/>
    <any>
         <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie6"/>
         <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie8"/>
         <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie9"/>
    </any>
  </replace-with>
```

IMO, I think the `nocache.js` bootstrap script should have a mechanism to alert the user when there is no permutation for a specific browser. Maybe calling the `gwt:onLoadErrorFn` (see my comment at gwt [issue#8135](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8135))

Comment: Agree, it would be nice to get a callback from bootstrap script if no permuation was found. But in your solution above I still have to create permutations for all browsers, right?

Comment: Yes that is the problem. But one advantage is that you can show to the user a customized screen informing about the issue.